# Create filter by hour

Tags: looker-studio

I'm creating a new chart that shows percentage of availability per day, on a single day I may have 2 different percentages (2 shifts).

When the chart presents the results, it actually sum both percentage and instead of showing shift 1 80% and shift 2 85% it groups on a single column with 165%

I was thinking of creating a calculated field that retrieves only the hour from a date field:

```
Start_Shift = todate(theoreticalshiftstarttimelocal,"%H")
```

Then create a filter, where field `Start_Shift` (type date):

```
Start_Shift = '6'
```

But is not bringing any results.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

```
Start_Shift = CAST(HOUR(theoreticalshiftstarttimelocal) AS TEXT)
```

And make sure you also change the Type to Text (of `Start_Shift`) in the data source (to ensure that the right type is enforced).